# Get string from theme's WXL file using bafunctions.dll, and change the text of a label

Tags: wix, installation, bootstrapper, burn

I'm using BURN with StandardBootstrapper application.
I'm also using bafunctions.dll to do some non trivial work in OnDetect().

I also want to programatically change a UI label based on stuff I do in OnDetect()

Questions are:
Can I access localized strings defined in the theme's WXL file using burn C API?

How can I change the text of a label element using burn C API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I change the text of a label element using burn C API?

Every time a page is loaded, WixStdBA will go through the text of each control on that page and format it through the engine's `FormatString` method. Note that in v3.x, controls not inside a page only get formatted once - before OnDetect is called. This is the only supported way for the bafunctions.dll to change the text of a control today. It would need access to the theme to do it directly.

Here's an example. Use a loc string for text of a control inside a page.

```
<Page>
    <Text>#(loc.MyCustomText)</Text>
</Page>
```

In the .wxl file, use a variable in the value of the loc string.

```
<String Id="MyCustomText">Static text plus [MyCustomTextVariable]</String>
```

In OnDetect or OnDetectComplete, set the value of the variable.

```
pEngine->SetVariableString(L"MyCustomTextVariable", sczValue);
```

> Can I access localized strings defined in the theme's WXL file using burn C API?

It's possible, but could be easier. You should file a feature request at http://wixtoolset.org/issues for bafunctions.dll to get access to the loaded loc strings and the theme.

The default .wxl file will be in the same directory as the bafunctions.dll.  You can use the LocUtil methods in locutil.h in dutil.lib to work with the .wxl file.